# Cakephp Email Not Working after Upgrade 3.5.2 --> 3.6.7

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I've upgraded my CakePHP app from 3.5.2 to 3.6.7.  My email functionality no longer works in the new version.

The email transport in config/app.php is:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'user@domain.com',
        'password' => 'secret',
        'client' => null,        
        'context' => [
            'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
                    ]
                    ],
            'tls' => true,      
            ],
    ],
```

And, the email sending code is:

```
 $email = new Email('default');
        $email->addTo($user['email'], $user['fullname']);
        $email->viewVars([
        'messagebody' => 'Hello, I am the message body of the email',
         ]);
        $email->setTemplate('mytemplate','mylayout')
        ->emailFormat('html')
        ->setFrom(['sender@domain.com' => __('Sender Name')])
        ->setSubject(__('Welcome Email'))
        ->helpers(['Html'])
        ->send();
```

This works perfectly in 3.5.2.  However, in 3.6.7, I get an error as follows:

> Notice (8): Undefined index: debugKitLog [ROOT\vendor\cakephp\debug_kit\src\Mailer\Transport\DebugKitTransport.php, line 37]
>   The context of the notice is:

```
$config = [
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => (int) 587,
'timeout' => (int) 30,
'username' => 'user@domain.com',
'password' => 'secret',
'client' => null,
'context' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    ]
],
'tls' => true
```

]
$originalTransport = null

Note, the same error occurs when using the Debug Kit's mail preview.  Again, in 3.5.2 there are no errors, and emails send correctly.  The errors only occur in 3.6.7.

Can anyone advise how to solve this?  And what changed in recent versions of CakePHP to cause it?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.
DBZ

Comment: Upgrade DebugKit.

Comment: Hi David, I have the latest version... 3.16.3, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue... was related to loading the debugkit plugin improperly in config/bootstrap.php

Comment: would you be so kind and share the exact solution?

Comment: Sure...  in config/bootstrap.php, the debug kit should be loaded like this:

`if (Configure::read('debug')) {
    Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);
}`

Comment: thank you for your help.
It makes me mad when e-mail stopped working on my app.